# JavaScript listener, "keypress" doesn't detect backspace?

Tags: javascript, keypress, addeventlistener

I'm using a `keypress` listener eg..

```
addEventListener("keypress", function(event){

}
```

However, this doesn't seem to detect a backspace which erases text...

Is there a different listener I can use to detect this?

Answer (score 201):

KeyPress event is invoked only for character (printable) keys, KeyDown event is raised for all including nonprintable such as <kbd>Control</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>BackSpace</kbd>, etc.

UPDATE:

> The keypress event is fired when a key is pressed down and that key normally produces a character value

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress).

Comment: Not strictly true: many non-printable keys fire `keypress` events in many browsers. See http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: In the current version of Mozilla, backspace and all is detected in keypress event.

Answer (score 86):

Try `keydown` instead of `keypress`.

The keyboard events occur in this order: `keydown`, `keyup`, `keypress`

The problem with backspace probably is, that the browser will navigate back on `keyup` and thus your page will not see the `keypress` event.

Comment: I haven't looked into the standards, but the event order (in Firefox 37 at least) seems to be `keydown` `keypress` `keyup`. http://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html

Comment: It also seems that, for key events in inputs, the character doesn't appear in the field until the `keyup` event is fired.

Comment: Last one - On iOS (8.2) the backspace key only fires a `keydown` event but the character isn't removed from the input until sometime after that.

Comment: this is the answer. this captures delete key press and Ctrl+V keypress

Answer (score 33):

The `keypress` event might be different across browsers.

I created a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/543zksjc/3/show/) to compare keyboard events (using the JQuery shortcuts) on Chrome and Firefox. Depending on the browser you're using a `keypress` event will be triggered or not -- backspace will trigger `keydown/keypress/keyup` on Firefox but only `keydown/keyup` on Chrome.

### Single keyclick events triggered

**on Chrome**

- `keydown/keypress/keyup` when browser registers a keyboard input (`keypress` is fired)
- `keydown/keyup` if no keyboard input (tested with alt, shift, backspace, arrow keys)
- `keydown` only for tab?

**on Firefox**

- `keydown/keypress/keyup` when browser  registers a keyboard input but also for backspace, arrow keys, tab (so here `keypress` is fired even with no input)
- `keydown/keyup` for alt, shift

---

This shouldn't be surprising because according to https://api.jquery.com/keypress/:

> Note: as the keypress event isn't covered by any official
>   specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may
>   differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.

The use of the keypress event type is deprecated by W3C (http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress)

> The keypress event type is defined in this specification for reference
>   and completeness, but this specification deprecates the use of this
>   event type. When in editing contexts, authors can subscribe to the
>   beforeinput event instead.

---

Finally, to answer your question, you should use `keyup` or `keydown` to detect a backspace across Firefox and Chrome.

---

**Try it out on here:**

```js
$(".inputTxt").bind("keypress keyup keydown", function (event) {
    var evtType = event.type;
    var eWhich = event.which;
    var echarCode = event.charCode;
    var ekeyCode = event.keyCode;

    switch (evtType) {
        case 'keypress':
            $("#log").html($("#log").html() + "<b>" + evtType + "</b>" + " keycode: " + ekeyCode + " charcode: " + echarCode + " which: " + eWhich + "<br>");
            break;
        case 'keyup':
            $("#log").html($("#log").html() + "<b>" + evtType + "</b>" + " keycode: " + ekeyCode + " charcode: " + echarCode + " which: " + eWhich + "<p>");
            break;
        case 'keydown':
            $("#log").html($("#log").html() + "<b>" + evtType + "</b>" + " keycode: " + ekeyCode + " charcode: " + echarCode + " which: " + eWhich + "<br>");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="inputTxt" type="text" />
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome answer - mostly for the explanation of the different ways to handle backspace across browsers

Comment: W3School is already done it: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_key_keycode2

Comment: Code Snippet was very helpful

Answer (score 20):

Something I wrote up incase anyone comes across an issue with people hitting backspace while thinking they are in a form field

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    /*
     * keyCode: 8
     * keyIdentifier: "U+0008"
    */
    if(e.keyCode === 8 && document.activeElement !== 'text') {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Prevent page from going back');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 15):

## event.key === "Backspace"

More recent and much cleaner: use `event.key`. No more arbitrary number codes!

```
note.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    const key = event.key; // const {key} = event; ES6+
    if (key === "Backspace") {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

Comment: In 2018 this is the best way to go about this!

Comment: I've been using key code 8 for backspace in every single language I worked with. Learn the ASCII codes, they're not arbitrary.

Comment: Just because you *have* been using doesn't mean there isn't a better option. `.key` is currently the recommended option by the docs. In addition, it supports various international keyboards with different mappings for any given key. They aren't *arbitrary* in the sense that they are fixed, but they are when reading code

Answer (score 9):

My numeric control:

```
function CheckNumeric(event) {
    var _key = (window.Event) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (_key > 95 && _key < 106) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (_key > 47 && _key < 58) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

<input type="text" onkeydown="return CheckNumerick(event);" />
```

try it

**BackSpace key code is 8**

Answer (score 3):

Use one of keyup / keydown / beforeinput events instead.

based on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) reference, keypress is deprecated and no longer recommended.

> The keypress event is fired when a key that produces a character value
>   is pressed down. Examples of keys that produce a character value are
>   alphabetic, numeric, and punctuation keys. Examples of keys that don't
>   produce a character value are modifier keys such as Alt, Shift, Ctrl,
>   or Meta.

if you use "beforeinput" be careful about it's [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/beforeinput_event#Browser_compatibility). the difference between "beforeinput" and the other two is that "beforeinput" is fired when input value is about to changed, so with characters that can't change the input value, it is not fired (e.g shift, ctr ,alt).

I had the same problem and by using keyup it was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying `keydown` and Backspace was not being captured. Switching to `keyup` worked for me.

```
addEventListener("keyup", function(event){

}
```

For reference, in case someone is using with `.on` for dynamically generated content.

```
$("body").on( "keyup", ".my-element", function(evt) {
      // Do something
});
```