# Iterate var names using a count with javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, var

I need to write a loop that will iterate the following 2 statements 44 times.

```
    window.onload = function() {
        var input1 = document.getElementById("alpha1");
        var input2 = document.getElementById("alpha2");
        var input3 = document.getElementById("alpha3");
        input1.onkeypress = alphaFilterKeypress;
        input2.onkeypress = alphaFilterKeypress;
        input3.onkeypress = alphaFilterKeypress;
    };
```

Comment: What have you tried? [loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) are quite simple constructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in it:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 45; i++) {
    var input = document.getElementById("alpha" + i);
    input.onkeypress = alphaFilterKeypress;
}
```

Comment: But how do I also increment the input1, input2, input3?

Comment: @KingJeremyTheWicked There is no need in defining 44 different variables, inside the loop you can use one.

Comment: I had gotten this far... but couldn't figure out how to loop to assign input1, input2, input3, etc.

Comment: Duh ... took out that comment. No need to have multiple variables.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through this 44 times, why not delegate the event? attach a single listener, and check if the id matches a given pattern

```
document.body.addEventlistener('keypress', alphaFilterKeypress, false);
```

You'll have to change the function definition - adding this check:

```
function alphaFilterKeypress(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (!target.id.match(/alpha[0-9]+/))
    {//don't handle the event
        //event was fired on an element with another (or no) id
        return e;//don't handle it here
    }
    //an element with id alpha[number] fired the event
    //handle the event
}
```

As you can see from [on this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843472/javascript-listener-keypress-doesnt-detect-backspace) the type of *"key"* event you're using is important. Where the `keypress` event does not pick up on keys like backspace, control etc... you might want to prefer using the `keydown` event. 
Play around with it, and work out which event suites your needs the best

Comment: It will bind `keypress` event to `body` element. There is no delegation here.

Comment: @VisioN: now there is, I was working on the edit - Showing how the handler needs to be altered

Comment: Yeah, but this is not `click` event, this is `keypress`. I'm not sure this will work.

Comment: @VisioN: It should work, but I added a related question on delegation/event listeners and various key* events.

Comment: You have a typo in method name: `addEventListener`.