# Why is my simple JavaScript numbers, and delete only, checker not working?

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple piece of JavaScript that is not working 100%, and I can't figure out why.

```
<input type="text" onKeyPress="return numbersOnly(event);" />
```

```
function numbersOnly(event){
    // Return "true" for all numbers and the delete (a.k.a., backspace) key.
    return ((event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || event.charCode == 8) ? true : false;
}
```

It will let me input just the numbers exactly like I want, but it won't pick up the delete (a.k.a., backspace) key.

EDIT: The weird thing is this works for me in IE 9 but not Firefox.

Comment: Related: [“keypress” doesn't detect backspace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843472/javascript-listener-keypress-doesnt-detect-backspace)

Comment: Works for me in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1fa495oq/

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I changed it to "keydown" but now nothing works.

Comment: @j08691 It does not work for me in Firefox (24.8.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're facing some cross browser issues with events.  Try this

```
function numbersOnly(event) {
    var key = (event.hasOwnProperty('charCode')) ? event.charCode : event.which;
    // Return "true" for all numbers and the delete (a.k.a., backspace) key.
    return ((key >= 48 && key <= 57) || key == 8) ? true : false;
}
```