# Angular 2 change event on every keypress

Tags: angular

The change event is only called after the focus of the input has changed. How can I make it so that the event fires on every keypress?

```xml
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="mymodel" (change)="valuechange($event)" />
{{mymodel}}
```

The second binding changes on every keypress btw.

Comment: keypress is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event

Answer (score 730, accepted):

I just used the event input and it worked fine as follows:

in .html file :

```xml
<input type="text" class="form-control" (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)">
```

in .ts file :

```typescript
onSearchChange(searchValue: string): void {  
  console.log(searchValue);
}
```

Comment: how do we delay for some time?

Comment: The (input) event is not supported in Edge and IE browsers. What is the alternative for this in Edge browser?

Comment: Thanks, perfect for Angular 6.

Comment: spent a lot of time on change detection and what not. In the end, found peace. Thank you for this!
PS: My problem was related to angular [formGroup], and I was using (change) before finding this post. Didn't know that (input) will work.

Comment: many thanks, I noticed (change) event triggers on blur, whilst this one when you type.

Comment: @MahmoudHboubati this may come a bit late, but you could delay the search by `setTimeout` and store the return value of that function. And every time before you do it again, you can reset that delayed execution via `clearTimeout`: `if (this.searchDelayHandle) clearTimeout(this.searchDelayHandle); this.searchDelayHandle = setTimeout(() => ..., 1000);`

Answer (score 237):

Use `ngModelChange` by breaking up the `[(x)]` syntax into its two pieces, i.e., property databinding and event binding:

```xml
<input type="text" [ngModel]="mymodel" (ngModelChange)="valuechange($event)" />
{{mymodel}}
```

```typescript
valuechange(newValue) {
  mymodel = newValue;
  console.log(newValue)
}
```

It works for the backspace key too.

Comment: nice, but do you know why this works? i would think that [(ngModel)]="mymodel" is just shorthand for what you have.

Comment: But when using the banana in a box syntax, it only changes the model, but you cant hook something on the change event.

Comment: That's a great answer for best two-way data binding. Should be the accepted answer!

Comment: backspace key is not updating the model

Comment: That solution is correct. However, be aware that ngModelChange is fired BEFORE the value updates. So the 'newValue' in this example contains the model WITHOUT the key you just pressed - so you don't have the updated model there. If you want to have the most recent model value, use the (keyup) event.

Comment: Use: [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" if you want to use it in a reactive from

Comment: with the latest update (angular 6) the (ngModelChange) event captures the latest value thereby avoiding the need to have [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"

Comment: This doesn't work for backspace. (keyup) event is best for all cases.

Comment: @SateeshKumarAlli which version of Angular do you have? For me it does detect backspace in Angular 6.1.3

Comment: @Jette I'm using 5.2.9

Comment: @SateeshKumarAlli  what is the final approach that you took. We are using 5.2.10 version and i have the same issue with backspace.

Comment: @AnveshReddy I'm using (input)="valuechange()"

Comment: Does not fire on <input type="datetime-local" ... >

Answer (score 155):

## The (keyup) event is your best bet.

Let's see why:

1. **(change)** like you mentioned triggers only when the input loses focus, hence is of limited use.
2. **(keypress)** triggers on key presses but doesn't trigger on certain keystrokes like the backspace.
3. **(keydown)** triggers every time a key is pushed down. Hence always lags by 1 character; as it gets the element state before the keystroke was registered.
4. **(keyup)** is your best bet as it triggers every time a key push event has completed, hence this also includes the most recent character.

#### So (keyup) is the safest to go with because it...

- registers an event on every keystroke unlike (change) event
- includes the keys that (keypress) ignores
- has no lag unlike the (keydown) event

Comment: As mentioned in one of the answers, input event works really well. `keyup` is for sure one of the safest options however, `input` event is one step ahead of `keyup`.  `keyup` unlike `input`, doesn't work if the value of textbox is changed by any other way e.g. binding.

Comment: Sagar, thank you very much. **This should be the Accepted Answer** as it is the only one to actually address `(change)` alongside a workaround and then some. The accepted answer totally sucks!

Comment: is there any particular reason you would want to do this over `(ngModelChange)`?

Comment: This should be the accepted and safest answer as it is native and gives you full control and it is very expressive, because everyone that reads it knows exactly when the event is fired.

Comment: Will this works when user copy the text from somewhere else and then paste it into our textbox?

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo No, it would not. Use (input) if you are looking for something like that.

Comment: @Sagar, I just tested this on Chrome and the keyup event fired after a paste once all keys were released. When you say this would not work, I wonder if it's browser/platform dependent?

Comment: (keyup) helped me with backspace keystroke, thank's a lot!

Comment: `keyup` as the name says only works with keys, so pasting with `Ctrl+v` is detected, while pasting with the mouse context menu is not.

Answer (score 40):

```xml
<input type="text" [ngModel]="mymodel" (keypress)="mymodel=$event.target.value"/>
{{mymodel}}
```

**Update**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event

> Warning: Since this event has been deprecated, you should use beforeinput or keydown instead.

Comment: works, but strangely the backspace key isn't recognized as a keypress?

Comment: You might want to use `keydown` or `keyup` instead. Some keys just don't fire on `keypress`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843472/javascript-listener-keypress-doesnt-detect-backspace

Comment: I have tried keydown, keyup and change events but when the input is w the event handler reports to me empty string; when the input is we the event handler reports to me w as the input. Can you please explain why this behavior?

Comment: Use keypress. The input hasn't changed yet on keydown.

Comment: It's strange, but I'm getting an input lag on this where the value doesn't contain the typed value until the next keypress.

Comment: The example is a bit flawed, because it doesn't make sense to bind `[ngModel]="..."` and `(keypress)="..."` to the same field (`mymodel`). It would make more sense to have something like `(keypress)="myKeyPressHandler($event.target.value)"`. I'm sure `(keypress)="$event.target.value"` alone always passes the most recent key value. If it doesn't a Plunker that allows to reproduce would be helpful. Usually `(ngModelChange)="..."` is a better option anyway. It also works better with `[ngModel]="..."`

Comment: keypress is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event

Answer (score 40):

A different way to handle such cases is to use [formControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) and subscribe to its `valueChanges` when your component is initialized, which will allow you to use **rxjs** operators for advanced requirements like performing http requests, apply a debounce until user finish writing a sentence, take last value and omit previous value, etc.

```javascript
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'some-selector',
  template: `
    <input type="text" [formControl]="searchControl" placeholder="search">
  `
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public searchControl: FormControl;
  public debounce: number = 400;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchControl = new FormControl('');
    this.searchControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(debounceTime(this.debounce), distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe(query => {
        console.log(query);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect.  This keeps the chatty noise down when using this for async http requests.  Also already sets up the change event listeners.  Brilliant!  Thanks!

Comment: In case of multiple controls, same code can be applied with `FormGroup`

Answer (score 23):

The secret event that keeps angular ngModel synchronous is the event call **input**. Hence the best answer to your question should be:

```xml
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="mymodel" (input)="valuechange($event)" />
{{mymodel}}
```

Comment: It does for me @AndreiDiaconescu

Comment: The (input) event is not supported in Edge and IE browsers. What is the alternative for this in Edge browser?

Answer (score 8):

```xml
<input type="text" (keypress)="myMethod(myInput.value)" #myInput />
```

archive .ts

```ts
myMethod(value:string){
...
...
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Ulric, please explain how your code solves the problem.

Comment: keypress is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event

Answer (score 6):

For Reactive Forms, you can subscribe to the changes made to all fields or just a particular field.

Get all changes of a FormGroup:

```
this.orderForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    console.dir(value);
});
```

Get the change of a specific field:

```
this.orderForm.get('orderPriority').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    console.log(value);
  });
```

Comment: Note that it will only be triggered on blur

Answer (score 5):

I managed to get this solved in Angular 11 by using the below code:

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="50" [value]="input.to" name="to"
        (input)="input.to=$event.target.value; experienceToAndFrom()">
```

And, the `experienceToAndFrom()` is a method in my component.

PS: I tried all the above solutions, but didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="mymodel" (keyup)="valuechange()" />
{{mymodel}}
```

Then do whatever you want with the data by accessing the bound `this.mymodel` in your .ts file.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the solution is:

```
[ngModel]="X?.Y" (ngModelChange)="X.Y=$event"
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been using keyup on a number field, but today I noticed in chrome the input has up/down buttons to increase/decrease the value which aren't recognized by keyup.

My solution is to use keyup and change together:

```
(keyup)="unitsChanged[i] = true" (change)="unitsChanged[i] = true"
```

Initial tests indicate this works fine, will post back if any bugs found after further testing.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered with multiple ways.
However, if you would like to look at another way, specific to adding some delay before you take any action on change event then you can use the debounceTime() method with angular form valuechanges(). This code need to be added in ngOnInit() hook or create a seprate method and call it from ngOnInit().

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formNameInputChange();
  }

  formNameInputChange(){
    const name = this.homeForm.get('name'); // Form Control Name
    name?.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(1000)).subscribe(value => {
      alert(value);
    });
  }
  // this is reactive way..
  homeForm = this.fb.group({
    name:['']
  });
```