# Angular2 - Keyup require a clarification

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In my app, conditionally i am adding a class. and when the user enter something i am checking the value and accordingly i am adding the class name. it works fine.

but it only updates on set of `(keyup)='0'` - setting some value on `keyup`. this is not like `angular 1` here.

so any one explain me why do we set the `(keyup)=0` here? and what it do for us?

here is my code :

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core"

@Component({

    selector : 'my-component',

    template : `
                <h2>My Name is: {{name}} 
                    <span [class.is-awesome]="formReplay.value === 'yes' ">So good</span>
                </h2>
                <input type="text" #formReplay (keyup)="0" />
                `,

    styles  : [`

        .is-awesome{
            color:green;
        }

    `]

})

export class MyComponent { 
    name = "My Name";   
}
```

Comment: Nothing, that keyup is doing nothing but triggering change detection. The `0` means nothing since having an empty event [produces an error](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3754).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Offical docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'loop-back',
  template:`
    <input #box (keyup)="0">
    <p>{{box.value}}</p>
  `
})
export class LoopbackComponent { }
```

look for this in offical docs.

> This won't work at all unless we bind to an event.
>
> Angular only updates the bindings (and therefore the screen) if we do
>   something in response to asynchronous events such as keystrokes.
>
> That's why we bind the keyup event to a statement that does ... well,
>   nothing. We're binding to the number 0, the shortest statement we can
>   think of. That is all it takes to keep Angular happy. We said it would
>   be clever!

Comment: Yes it is there Eric ! :-)

Comment: A better solution is here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/35368127/968003.
`<input type="text" [ngModel]="mymodel" (keypress)="mymodel=$event.target.value"/>
{{mymodel}}`

The current one doesn't work for `input[type="number"]` when instead of entering a value, the user clicks on the up/down arrow. Then the value in the input is changing, but the `keyup` event isn't firing up.

Comment: Why are we binding to a statement? In the docs it says we have to bind to an event. Why do we even have to bind keyup to anything if we have a template reference variable?