# Angular, why our local variable updates when i bind an event with a 0 value?

Tags: angular

```
<input #myInput (keyup)="0">

<p>{{myInput.value}}</p>
```

why that keyup event updates the myInput.value ? What the logic that makes this happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 - Keyup require a clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001757/angular2-keyup-require-a-clarification)

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind to an event so that the binding/screen is updated. Thus, `(keyup)="0"` is a shortcut to update bindings on keyup.

See in the official docs: https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Answer (score 0):

the #myInput creates a template reference and hence {{myInput.value}} gives the value of the input element