# Angular 2 binding vs event detection

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a page with multiple dropdowns as filters and I have a function listener for when any dropdown changes to update filtering.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="filters.foo" (change)="update()">...</select>
<select [(ngModel)]="filters.bar" (change)="update()">...</select>
<select [(ngModel)]="filters.quz" (change)="update()">...</select>
<select [(ngModel)]="filters.lol" (change)="update()">...</select>
<select [(ngModel)]="filters.wtf" (change)="update()">...</select>
```

But when my `update()` function is executed the filters object hasn't been updated yet.

[This plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/e69kzOw5ZJgMo2cyFCtG?p=preview) shows the issue, load the page and type anything on the inputs:

How can I call `update()` only after the model has been updated?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: Instead of listening to native events we listen to `ngModelChange` event.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="filters.foo" (ngModelChange)="update()">...</select>
```

[I read somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359358/angular-2-change-event-on-every-keypress) you can remove the parenthesis from `ngModel` like this

```
<!-- THIS DIDN'T WORK FOR ME -->
<select [ngModel]="filters.foo" (ngModelChange)="update()">...</select>
```

But this didn't work for me so I left the parenthesis and now it works perfectly :)

Comment: The 2nd snippet will not work because `[property]` propagates the data from component to template only so when you update it manually by selecting the dropdown's option, it will not update `filters.foo`. For that you  need to use `(property)` syntax that propagates the data from template to component. If you need both behaviors, you have to use `[(property)]` which you have used in the first snippet - I just wanted to clarify what went wrong.