# Angular 2 - Form is invalid when browser autofill

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a Login Form which has email and password fields.

I've chosen for browser autofill.

The problems is: When browser autofills login form, both fields are pristine and untouched, so the submit button is disabled.

If I click on disabled button, it enables and fires submit action, what is nice. But the default disabled aspect is pretty bad what can make some users disappointed.

Do you have some ideas about how to deal with?

Comment: were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: @JohnDizzle:  Did you guys able to get it work? if yes then how? :)

Comment: @Denish No, I must disappoint you. This seems to be an open problem for everyone in the community...

Comment: @Denish, If you have a reactive form, then something like [disabled]="user.invalid" should work

Comment: It might be related to this issue here: The autofill values only become available after user interacts with the form: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3414

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by also checking if the form was touched when displaying error messages.
So, for example, the submit button looks like this

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="loginFormGroup.invalid && loginFormGroup.touched" />
```

Comment: So the button will still be activated if the fields are empty when the page load with this solution

Comment: This is the most elegant, and error-proof declarative solution, imho

Answer (score 4):

I seem to have solved this by just simulating a click on the page `AfterViewInit`.

Js :

```js
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    document.querySelector('body').click();
}
```

With JQuery :

```js
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $('body').click();
}
```

Chrome 67.0.3396.99, Angular 5.1.0

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with the `ChangeDetectorRef` Provider.

Simply do a manual `detectChanges()` before you check if the input is valid.

If you aren't able to check after a button click, then hear on the Input-Event of the Input-Element with the event-binding `(input)=changedetectorfunc()` and call the `changeDetector` in this function.

Therefore it must work.

Hope, it helps you.

useful links:

- https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef
- [Angular 2 change event on every keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359358/angular-2-change-event-on-every-keypress)

Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

#### There are two ways to solve this problem

- Use CSS pseudo class -webkit-autofill it will detect the autofill.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:aut

- Use AutofillMonitor package from angular/cdk module which monkey patch the Validators Since RequiredValidator is not able to acknowledge autofill input.

https://gist.github.com/kherock/fad4c320c5894ec68373588e338955c5

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem.

I solved it by:
- removing the `Validators.required` validator for the password field in the component
- using the `<input ... required ...>` directive at the  tag in the template

Answer (score -2):

this is not the best practice for code  but it will work for sure-

if you are having two way binding then its very easy task just check for length of both textbox if it is greater then zero then return false else return true and call the method in disabled attribute. 
Method-

```
    validcheck() {
         return username.length <= 0 || password.length <= 0;     
    }
```

and call the method inside button disabled attribute

```
    <button [disabled]="validcheck()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score -3):

Had the same problem too. I'm not sure if this is the best way, but I was able to get it to work by adding AfterViewChecked

```
import { Component, AfterViewChecked } from "@angular/core";

export class LoginComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
    // Beware! Called frequently!
    // Called in every change detection cycle anywhere on the page
    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        console.log(`AfterViewChecked`);
        if (this.usr.userName) {
            // enable to button here.
            console.log("found username in AfterViewChecked");
        }
    }
}
```

or you might be able to try Angular2's other Lifecycle Hooks
https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview

Comment: That will enable the button but the form itself will still be invalid, so submission will not go through.

Answer (score -3):

According to the offical docs

```
"pristine" means the user hasn't changed the value since it was displayed in this form
```

So if you have a validation in your form it's a better approach to check if the form is "valid" or "invalid"

```
<button [disabled]="formName.invalid">Submit</button>
```

So it doesn't matter if the form is pristine or not.