# Angular 2 HostListener keypress detect escape key?

Tags: javascript, angular, escaping, keypress

I am using the following method to detect keypresses on a page. My plan is to detect when the Escape key is pressed and run a method if so. For the moment I am just attempting to log which key is pressed. However the Escape key is never detected.

```
@HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  console.log(event);
  let x = event.keyCode;
  if (x === 27) {
      console.log('Escape!');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Try it with a `keydown` or `keyup` event to capture the `Esc` key. In essence, you can replace `document:keypress` with `document:keydown.escape`:

```js
@HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: To decide which one of the key events to use, check this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46403258/3380547

Comment: How does the event specification work? `document:keydown.escape` seems rather arbitrary. Is there any documentation on the valid syntax? I could not even find a proper implementation in Angular of the HostListener directive functionality, the listeners seem to be buried deep in the internals.

Comment: If this doesn't work, try 'window:keydown.espace' instead.

Comment: `escape` should be `Escape` now

Answer (score 43):

It worked for me using the following code:

```
const ESCAPE_KEYCODE = 27;

@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.keyCode === ESCAPE_KEYCODE) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

or in shorter way:

```
@HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(evt: KeyboardEvent) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Note that KeyCode is being [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), you can replace with [event.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) and match against the string "Escape". No need to use codes, having the side effect of making the code easy to read.

Comment: Nice `document:keydown.escape` so we do not need to do that `27` check. Thanks.

Answer (score 32):

## Modern approach, `event.key == "Escape"`

The old alternatives (`.keyCode` and `.which`) are Deprecated.

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.key === "Escape") {
        // Do things
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work in IE 11, where the key is called "Esc":  if (event.key === "Escape" || event.key === "Esc")

Comment: Good catch! To be fair though, the title is 'Modern' :D

Comment: I was having problems consistently capturing char code 13 (enter key) when using a barcode scanner with an angular component.  Changing from keypress to keydown resolved this for me.

Answer (score 11):

In my case (with Angular 10) `keydown.escape` works fine to track event `escape` by console.log():

```ts
@HostListener('keydown.escape')
fn() {
 console.log();
}
```

But Angular change detector work fine only with `keyup.escape`.

Comment: I needed to make this `@HostListener('document:keydown.escape')` for it to work, inspired by @Gibolt

Answer (score 5):

Angular makes this easy with the @HostListener decorator. This is a function decorator that accepts an event name as an argument. When that event gets fired on the host element it calls the associated function.

```
@HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: 
    KeyboardEvent) {
    this.closeBlade();
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

keydown and keyup seem to work: http://embed.plnkr.co/VLajGbWhbaUhCy3xss8l/