# Add (input) to html tag dynamically in Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, events

I have some html that is dynamically generated - I cannot modify it directly.

In this html is an `<input class="MyInputClass">` with class specified (without id) and many other atrributes. I would like to handle this input (it's text) so that it does something (let's say: writes itself to console) when something is written to this input.

If I had an access to this in html I would do it like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)">

public onSearchChange(searchValue : string ) {
    console.log(searchValue);
}
```

Source: [Angular 2 change event on every keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359358/angular-2-change-event-on-every-keypress)

Is it possible to inject such handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

When you write

```
<input type="text" (input)="doSomething()" />
```

You don't actually tell

> I want this input to make something on the input event

But you actually tell

> I want Angular to create an event handler that will make something on the input event.

This means, dynamically generated HTML won't have the capacity of having any Angular feature.

**BUT**, what you can do, is in your component, in the `ngOnInit` function, create window functions, that you will destroy in your `ngOnDestroy` function.

Something like this

```
ngOnInit() {
  window['onXXXInput'] = (value) => {
    /* do something */
  }
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  delete(window['onXXXInput']);
}
```

Now in your dynamically generated HTML; you can simply do

```
<input type="text" oninput="window.onXXXInput(this.value)" />
```