# Angular2 code on when some change in Textbox how its Reflect back to component

Tags: angular2-forms, angular4-forms

Here i have requirement like if i type type anything in Textbox it should be Reflect back to Component

```
<label> Search FRom Table:</label> <input (change)="someval()">

Someval(){
//Here i need that TextBox value
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in **Two way data binding** method and so on.

Html Looks like following

```
    <label> Search From Table:</label>
    <input name="searchTxt" [(ngModel)]="searchTxt" (input)="someval()">

    {{searchTxt}} <!-- here iam printed html file also -->
```

Typescript File:

```
//Add one variable 
public searchTxt:any;

someval(){
 console.log("Here iam printed variable",this.searchTxt);
}
```

Make sure you have to import Forms Module in app module file
other wise it show error like this
[image]

app.module.ts

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

imports: [
    FormsModule,
],
```

For more details about related here, please visit:

https://www.code-sample.com/2017/05/angular2-input-textbox-change-events.html

[Angular 2 change event on every keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359358/angular-2-change-event-on-every-keypress)