# regex to replace non numeric

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I want to replace all my non numeric characters with an empty string. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862130/strip-all-non-numeric-characters-from-string-in-javascript)

I am trying to replace the value of an input element on change. But when I use above, it is not replacing until I press a number.

**Each non-digit I type stays until I type a digit**

Ex: 2aaaaa will not be replaced. But as soon as `2aaaa3` is typed it will replace all the a's and it becomes 23

Is this the normal behaviour? How can I achieve my requirement.

component.ts

```
mobileChanged = () => {
    this.mobile = this.mobile.replace(/\D/g,'');
  };
```

angular component.html

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="mobile" (ngModelChange)="mobileChanged()">
```

Comment: Are you saying each non-digit you type stays until you type a digit?  Can you provide any information about the field this happens with?

Comment: So what calls `mobileChanged`?

Comment: @epascarello updated

Comment: @bula I've added an answer for you, is that helped?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keyup` from jQuery or `onkeyup` from Javascript.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("input").keyup(function() {
    let v = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    this.value = v;
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's the usual behaviour for `ngModelChange` but seems you need `onkeyup` event here to replace **Non-digits**. Something like-

```js
function mobileChanged() {
  var txtinput = document.getElementById("fname");
  var x = txtinput.value.replace(/\D/g,'');
  txtinput.value = x;
}
```

```html
<input id ="fname" type='text' onkeyup="mobileChanged()">
```

**See if you still have confusion**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46403258/1138192