# Properly handle onchange event on Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs

I've been working with React for the past years, and I'm pretty new to Angular. I am currently trying to create an input field with a normalizer. I can easily do this as a React component, but I can't seem to translate it correctly into an Angular component. If I have to do this with React, my code would be like

```
const Input = (props) => {
   const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

   const handleChange = (e) => {
       // insert pre-processing logic
       setValue(e.target.value);
   };

   return (
      <>
         <p>Value: {value}</p>
         <input {...props} value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
      </>
   );
}
```

I tried coding this in Angular:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  template: `
    <p>Value: {{value}}</p>
    <input (change)="onInputChange($event)" [value]="value" />
  `
})
export class InputComponent {
  value: string = '';
  onInputChange(e) {
    // insert pre-processing logic
    this.value = e.target.value;
  }
}
```

My issue with the Angular component is I have to click outside the input field or trigger onblur before the `(change)` event is fired, unlike the React one where the `onChange` event is fired every single time the user types. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Use the `(input)=""` event: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359358/angular-2-change-event-on-every-keypress