# How can I add a keypress event Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, filter, angular-material

I am setting an input field to a variable I am defining, this is used to filter through my table on the front-end. It does not want to return any values unless a key is entered within the input field. How can I get the filter to work without the input field expecting back a key event. I want it to return values immediately when the `'filteredValue'` is assigned.

HTML

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" *ngIf="filteredValue">
  <mat-label>Filter 1</mat-label>
  <input matInput 
         type="text" 
         (input)="doFilter($event.target.value)" 
         placeholder="Ex. BMW" 
         value="{{filteredValue | lowercase }}">
</mat-form-field>
```

component.ts

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  if (this.urlMM) {
    this.filteredValue = this.urlMM + ' ' + this.urlMake + ' ' + this.urlYear;
  }
}

public doFilter = (value: string) => {
  this.dataSource.filter = value.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: So you want your value as soon as you type something in your input field? If so you should check the answer of the user 'Saga' on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359358/angular-2-change-event-on-every-keypress

Comment: I am already assigning a value to the input field. But the filter only returns values when I edit the textbox. I want the values to be filtered as soon as the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use keypress

```js
doFilter(filterKety) {
console.log(filterKey)
if(filterKey.length > 2){
// your logic

} 
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" *ngIf="filteredValue">
  <mat-label>Filter 1</mat-label>
  <input matInput 
         type="text" 
         (keypress)="doFilter($event.target.value)" 
         placeholder="Ex. BMW" 
         value="{{filteredValue | lowercase }}">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: This still does not provide the desired solution. When the page loads the input field already has a value assigned ("filteredValue"). I want this value to filter through the table as soon as the data is returned within the table.