# input not update view ngmodelchange

Tags: angular, ngmodel, angular-ngmodelchange

I want to remove the letters and leave only numbers, the validation is fine but the input view does not update correctly.
the variable "quantity" does change its value and I can show it below with
`<p> {{quantity}} </p>`

**button-add.component.html**

```
<input
      [ngModel]="quantity"
      (ngModelChange)="quantity = changeQuantity($event)"
    />
    <p> {{quantity}} </p>
```

**button-add.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'button-add-button',
  templateUrl: './button-add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button-add.component.scss'],
})
export class ButtonAddComponent implements OnInit {
  quantity: number = 10;
  constructor() {}

  public changeQuantity(cant: string) {
    return parseInt(cant.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, ''));
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: [Angular Forms: Why is ngModelChange late when updating ngModel value](https://indepth.dev/posts/1331/angular-forms-why-is-ngmodelchange-late-when-updating-ngmodel-value).

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using the `ngModel` is incorrect, you need to correct that first, after that instead of model change do It on the `keyup` event, kindly refer to below code

```
<input [(ngModel)]="quantity" (keyup)="changeQuantity($event)" />
<p> {{quantity}} </p>
```

Also instead of directly setting value in your `.html` keep it in your `.ts` and reassign it to quantity, refer to below code

```
public changeQuantity(cant: any) {
  this.quantity = parseInt(cant.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, ''));
}
```

Please find the behaviour of various events which will help you to decide when to trigger `changeQuantity()`

- **keypress or input:** on every next keystroke your value will get
  updated
- **change**: outside click of control will trigger this
- **keyup**: reflects immediately but it will show a slight flicker

For better clarification on events, refer [best bet event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46403258)