# charCode function returns 0 value for backspace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to filter user input by using a custom jQuery function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#afm').keypress(function(key){

    var len = $('#afm').val().length;
    console.log(key.charCode);

    if( key.charCode < 8   || (key.charCode > 8 && key.charCode < 48) || key.charCode > 57 && len < 9){ 

        $('#tip-afm').text("error");
        return false;
    }
    else
        $('#tip-afm').text("");
 })
})
```

Whenever i press backspace,  console.log  displays charCode as 0.
As far as i know 8 is code assigned to backspace..
Am i doing something wrong?
Do i have to change the code to handle backspace's code as 0?Or this may lead to errors in the future?

Comment: You should use `keyCode` instead of `charCode`. `console.log(event.keyCode);

Comment: What OS/Browser are you using ? Eg. firefox for android have `keyCode=0` to letters and backspace, in chrome for android `keyCode=229`

Comment: I am using Firefox..But how can i restrict user input independent of the browser being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use **jQuery.keyup()** instead of **jQuery.keypress()** and use **key.keyCode** instead of **key.charCode**.

Code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#afm').keyup(function(key){

    var len = $('#afm').val().length;
    console.log(key.keyCode);

    if( key.keyCode < 8   || (key.keyCode > 8 && key.keyCode < 48) || key.keyCode > 57 && len < 9){ 

        $('#tip-afm').text("error");
        return false;
    }
    else
        $('#tip-afm').text("");
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="afm">
<div id="tip-afm">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this to get the code of the pressed key

```
var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
```

Answer (score 2):

Check chars using this:

`key.which` and `key.keyCode`

Answer (score 2):

The `keypress` event might not be fired when the users enters a backspace. Check this answer, you might want to use a `keyup`instead. Check also my answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30108293/2314737

Comment: I decided to do this by using charCode,it turns out to be the easiest solution,since i charCode is 0 for all browsers the page will support(firefox,chrome and explorer).Your jsfiddle helped me figuring out this.Any other idea/advice available is highly appreciated:)