# Dynamic font resize

Tags: javascript, text, dynamic

This script resize text based on the text length. All works fine but the text does not resize up when deleting characters. what's missing? Hoping there is a script guru around to help me!

```js
  $('#location').keypress(function() {

    var textLength = $(this).val().length;

    if (textLength < 20) {
      // Do noting 
    } else if (textLength < 40) {
      $(this).css('font-size', '16px');
    } else if (textLength > 40) {
      $(this).css('font-size', '24px');
    }
    //console.log(textLength);
  });
```

```css
#location {
  font-size: 24px;
  outline: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="location" placeholder="Placeholder Text" />
```

Comment: [KeyPress event is invoked only for character (printable) keys, KeyDown event is raised for all including nonprintable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4843502/427146)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript listener, "keypress" doesn't detect backspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843472/javascript-listener-keypress-doesnt-detect-backspace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this you wanted to do?

`Kepress` works for printable characters only. In order to detect backspace and delete use `keyup` or `keydown`

```js
$(document).on('keyup keydown','#location',function() {
 
    var textLength = $(this).val().replace(/\s+/g,'').length; // first replace spaces then count
    console.log("Length without spaces "+textLength);
    if (textLength < 20) {
       $(this).css('font-size', '24px');
    } else if (textLength < 40) {
      $(this).css('font-size', '16px');
    } else if (textLength > 40) {
      $(this).css('font-size', '24px');
    }
    //console.log(textLength);
  });
```

```css
#location {

  outline: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="location" placeholder="Placeholder Text" />
```

Comment: Wow! You made it look too easy! Exactly what I was after! Thanking you tons!

Comment: Thanks again. What would i have to do to ignore spaces in the textLenght count?

Comment: @Exposian done. updated my answer. now how many spaces you give it will not be considered. I'm replacing spaces with empty ''

Answer (score 0):

`keypress` will not fire on backspace, so change ot to `keyup` instaed

```
$('#location').keyup(function() {

    var textLength = $(this).val().length;

    if (textLength < 20) {
      // Do noting 
    } else if (textLength < 40) {
      $(this).css('font-size', '16px');
    } else if (textLength > 40) {
      $(this).css('font-size', '24px');
    }
    //console.log(textLength);
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

1. keypress will not fire on backspace, so change it to **keyup** instead
2. Remove the else condition and made use of only **if**

   ```
   $('#location').keyup(function() {

      var textLength = $(this).val().length;

      if (textLength < 40) {
          $(this).css('font-size', '16px');
      }
      if (textLength > 40) {
         $(this).css('font-size', '24px');
      }
       //console.log(textLength);
   });
   ```