# Block entering values in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written below lines of code for blocking users to enter some values in  textbox:

```
$(".block-keypress").keypress(function(e){
  return false;
});
```

It is working fine but backspace is not blocked.

Comment: Why not just set the field as `readonly`? No JS required

Comment: what about the read-only value on the textbox if you want users don't enter any value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript listener, "keypress" doesn't detect backspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843472/javascript-listener-keypress-doesnt-detect-backspace)

Comment: Due to an important reason i cannot set the textbox to read only

Comment: not sure why you are wanting to stop them entering, possibly use the disabled attribute?

Comment: @Nida and what is that important reason? You can set and unset `readonly` in javascript when needed. Anyway, check linked question above, it has an answer.

Comment: If you don't want users to enter or modify values at all, then it seems that a form input wasn't the way to go with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with new code

use `keydown` instead of `keypress`

```js
$(".block-keypress").keydown(function(e) {
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="block-keypress" value="test">
```

Comment: no it doesn't if you already have a value set suppose. Then try this out backspace will still work.