# Counter is not changing color according to the function

Tags: javascript, dom, preventdefault, onkeypress

the counter needs to turn red when i reach 10 characters. When i reach 10 characters, i have to press any button again in order for the counter to turn red. When i delete the characters, the counter remains red instead of going back to black.

```
<script>

            function ceScriu(){

              var numeInput = document.querySelector("[name='nume']");
              var nume = numeInput.value;
              var nu = nume.toString().toLowerCase();
              var divInput = document.querySelector("[name='divul']");
              var div = nu.length;

              document.querySelector("[name='divul']").innerHTML = div;



                numeInput.onkeypress = function(){
                if(div === 10){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    divInput.classList.add("counter");


                }else{

                    divInput.classList.remove("counter");

                }
                }



            }



</script>
```

I want the counter to turn red when i enter the 10th character and i want the counter to turn back to black when i start deleting characters after i reached the 10th.

Comment: this is the full code, you can also run it https://plnkr.co/edit/Zs4bmntiTcXqjIXICgz6?p=preview. The counter is at the far right side of the fieldset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all your answers. Some of them were of help and led me to this result.
It seems that all i needed to do was just add 2 more IF statements. 
I'm adding the code here.

```
        function ceScriu(){

          var numeInput = document.querySelector("[name='nume']");
          var nume = numeInput.value;
          var nu = nume.toString().toLowerCase();
          var divInput = document.querySelector("[name='divul']");
          var div = nu.length;

          document.querySelector("[name='divul']").innerHTML = div;



            numeInput.onkeypress = function(){
            if(div >9){

                event.preventDefault();

            }else{

                divInput.classList.remove("counter");

            }
            }

            if(div<10){

                divInput.classList.remove("counter");

            }

            if(div>9){
                document.querySelector("[name='divul']").classList.add("counter");


            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

1.) By declaring the variables before the onkeypress, you're passing the original values. It might be better to check the length/value again inside the keypress function.

2.) Onkeypress does not work with backspaces. You should use "onkeyup" in order to detect the backspace change.

3.) If you want to detect 10 or more characters (and keep the box red until the length is less than 10), you should use `div >= 10` as a comparison (more than or equal to 10)

`

```
        function ceScriu(){
          // *1 
          var numeInput = document.querySelector("[name='nume']");
          var nume = numeInput.value;
          var nu = nume.toString().toLowerCase();
          var divInput = document.querySelector("[name='divul']");
          var div = nu.length;

          document.querySelector("[name='divul']").innerHTML = div;



   // *2         numeInput.onkeypress = function(){
                /* New event check*/
                   numeInput.onkeyup = function(){
                /* End new event check*/

                /* New length Check */
                 let nume = numeInput.value;
                 let nu = nume.toString().toLowerCase();
                 let div = nu.length;
               /* End new length check */

   // *3         if(div === 10){
                /* New comparison */
                   if(div >= 10){
                /* End new comparison */

                event.preventDefault();



                divInput.classList.add("counter");


            }else{

                divInput.classList.remove("counter");

            }
            }



        }
```

`

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for the help but i need to use the  prevendDefault to stop the user from inputing more than 10 characters and i must use the onkeypress event(its a requirement for this exercise). So far my code works but my issue is that the counter does not turn red on the 10th key press, but it does on the 11th. And when i start to delete the characters, the counter remains red.

Comment: You can use the 'maxlength="10"' attribute in the input tag to prevent users from entering more 10 characters. As for the onkeypress event, you might want to check out its limitation from the [other answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843472/javascript-listener-keypress-doesnt-detect-backspace)

Answer (score 2):

`onkeypress` is not suitable in this case. You can use either `onkeyup` or `oninput` event. To restrict the inputs up to certain length you can use `maxlength` attribute.

Try the following way:

```js
function ceScriu(el){
  var divInput = document.querySelector("[name='divul']");
  var div = el.value.trim().length;
  document.querySelector("[name='divul']").textContent = div;
  if(div === 10){
    divInput.classList.add("counter");
  }
  else{
    divInput.classList.remove("counter");
  }

}
```

```css
.counter{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<input name="nume" oninput="ceScriu(this)" maxlength="10"/>

<div name="divul"></div>
```

Comment: the thing is that i need to use the preventDefault on the onkeypress event as it is a requirement for the exercise.

Comment: @ZiatcoFelix, as I already mentioned that is not the suitable event for this. I am not sure why do you need to use *preventDefault* while you can achieve that with a simple attribute setting:)

Comment: this code is part of an exercise and the requirement for it is to use the preventDefault to stop the characters at 10. Trust me, i would've wanted to use the maxlength since its a much easier approach.

Comment: @ZiatcoFelix, *onkeypress* event is invoked only for character (printable) keys, it will not work for backspace......

Comment: check the code below, i figured it out. It seems that it worked when the main function had the "oninput" event and inside that, i called the onkeypress. Anyway, thanks for the help. Next time i need to input a limit of characters, i will use maxlength.

Answer (score 2):

You need define a style ".counter" first and put the script and style inside the  tags, your code works when you try to press 11 times, if i put 1234567890 and try to put another, the style changes and set the red color

```
.counter{
color:red;
width:100px;
}




<script>


            function ceScriu(){

              var numeInput = document.querySelector("[name='nume']");
              var nume = numeInput.value;
              var nu = nume.toString().toLowerCase();
              var divInput = document.querySelector("[name='divul']");
              var div = nu.length;

              document.querySelector("[name='divul']").innerHTML = div;



                numeInput.onkeypress = function(){
                if(div === 10){
                    document.querySelector("[name='divul']").classList.add("counter");
                    event.preventDefault();

                }else{

                    divInput.classList.remove("counter");

                }
                }



            }



</script>


</head>
```

Comment: i tried it and it still changes colors at the 11th keypress. Also when i delete the characters, the counter still remains red.