# React onKeyPress event isn't detecting backspace

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onkeypress

I have a `handleBackspace` function that does something if backspace is being pressed.

I tried this:

```
const handleBackspace = (e) => {
    if(e.keyCode === 8) {
        console.log('1')
    }
}

//
<input onKeyPress={handleBackspace}>
```

But that doesn't work. (I tried it with keyCode `13` [enter] and it worked. But keyCode `8` [backspace] doesn't work) Can someone show me a solution?

Comment: Are you attempting to map [backspace] or [delete] key?  [delete] is 46.  Also, if you log the event `e` what is the `keyCode`?

Comment: I want to detect the backspace

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `onKeyPress`? Because for that event, `keyCode` will always be 0. Have you tried using `onKeyDown`?

Comment: It works. Thanks. I don't really know the difference between them

Comment: @Roy More info can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1898#issuecomment-49563013)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript listener, "keypress" doesn't detect backspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843472/javascript-listener-keypress-doesnt-detect-backspace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As can be read [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1898#issuecomment-49563013), `onKeyPress` only receives `charCode` instead of `keyCode`.

This gives us three possible answers to this issue:

- Either change the event to `onKeyDown`
- Change the listener to check `e.charCode`
- Use `e.which`, which will work for both `onKeyPress` and `onKeyDown`.

Answer (score 1):

`onKeyDown` detects `keyCode` events.

Try changing it to `onKeyDown` event.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-class-component-kzv2k?file=/src/index.js

```
  handleBackspace = e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 8) {
      console.log("1");
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <input onKeyDown={this.handleBackspace} />;
  }
```